# Can't get the value for the location of the touch through the .kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
class Main(App):
   def touched(self,touch):
      print(touch)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Main().run()
```

main.kv

```
FloatLayout:
    on_touch_move:app.touched(touch)
```

NameError: name 'touch' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `args` in the `kv`:

```
FloatLayout:
    on_touch_move: app.touched(*args)
```

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords).

And then the `touched()` method can be defined as:

```
def touched(self, instance, touch):
    print(touch)
```